# How do I set up my mac ftp client with an amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: macos, ftp, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

So far I have done the following:

1. Deployed amazon ec2 instance.
2. Received certificate/key from instance on desktop.
3. Have ftp cyberduck on my mac.

What else is remaining?

Im stuck at the puddy part for converting the key on my desktop.

Comment: I'm using FileZilla and easy to connect without any issue, check this out for step by step instructions : http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI

Answer (score 2):

If your EC2 machine is running an SSH server, you basically are ready to go. See the [Cyberduck manual about Public Key Authentication](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/sftp#PublicKeyAuthentication), especially this part:

> In the Connection Dialog or the Bookmark editor in Cyberduck select Use Public Key Authentication and select the private key in your .ssh directory.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://youtu.be/hd4oL3WIPVM) video for step by step instructions

Open Cyberduck - > Open Connection -> Select SFTP from drop down
Provide necessary parameters and under more options
Click "Use public key authentication" and specify your path to .pem file.
Then press connect button

Follow [this](http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI) if you like to use FileZilla.